# Do waterproof RJ45 connectors with integrated magnetics exist?

Tags: ethernet

I've been searching for days and can't seem to find a rugged RJ-45 Ethernet connector with integrated magnetics. Probably it would be good enough if the connector was just potted so water cannot leak through.

Is there a reason why such items don't exist?

Comment: what is the application that you want this for? ... you can get a waterproof RJ-45 connector that you can use to make a short extension between the ethernet controller and the enclosure ... `ethernet ctrl` ---> `RJ45 cable end` ---> `short cable` --> `waterproof RJ-45 plug`

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/a/assmann-wsw-components/waterproof-rj45-series-plugs-and-jacks

Comment: The application is a flexible device without an enclosure. The ethernet connector should be mounted directly to the flex PCB and then the whole thing will be coated with some rubber.

Comment: discrete transformer and this .... https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/assmann-wsw-components/A-RJ45DFR/AE10166-ND/1089537

Comment: Thanks that's basically what I had to do (although with a similar connector because that one is discontinued).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

Waterproof connectors are typically mounted to a bulkhead and Ethernet connectors with integrated magnetics have to be mounted close to the PHY chip. Ruggedized RJ45 is kind of a sloppy thing anyway.

People who care about ruggedized connectors (and care a bit less about cost) often use a different connector than RJ45 for 'Ethernet' (such as M12/military circular connectors).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that at least one manufacturer (Harting) is now offering M12 connectors with integrated magnetics. They are much too expensive for my application, but at least I can say that this appears to confirm your answer.